# Shipping Price Promotion - Reduced shipping rate based on quantity of specific products

Tags: shipping, ce-1.9.0.1, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'd like to set up a price promotion that reduces the shipping cost by 50% on specific (categorised) products, once cart quantity increases past 1.

- So for 1 item, shipping is 9.95.
- For 2 items, shipping is 50% off for the second item, 9.95+(9.95/2)= 14.93
- For 3 items, shipping is 50% off for the second and third items,
  9.95+((9.95/2)+(9.95/2)= 19.90

I can't find a way to manage this in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

So, the only answer to this is to set up the tablerates.csv with those prices. So far I'm unable to find an alternate solution.